# Categories vs. Page Site Organization

Tags: categories, pages, slug, hierarchical

I need to organize the pages on my website so that they appear with the proper hierarchy.  The problem is that the category-derived page is appearing outside my hierarchy.  This is the current hierarchy if you are on my site today:

```
Home                    mysite.com
  -> Internal (page)    mysite.com/internal
       -> Docs (page)   mysite.com/internal/docs
  -> Policy (category)  mysite.com/category/policy
```

I need the policy category page to appear under Internal, which is accessible only by my registered users, such as:

```
Home                         mysite.com
  -> Internal (page)         mysite.com/internal
       -> Docs (page)        mysite.com/internal/docs
       -> Policy (category)  mysite.com/internal/policy
```

I have other (External/Public) category pages that need to be handed differently.  Any ideas as to how I can make this happen would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched everything over to a categories model, so that I now have this category hierarchy:

```
Internal
  -- Docs
  -- Policy
```

I'll have to figure out how to customize the `/category/internal/` page layout later, but that's lower priority compared to some of the other things on my plate right now.  This arrangement meets my immediate needs.

**Update**

I've finalized the architecture using a 301 redirect for the top-level category page, so that now what I have is this:

```
Internal (category) -- 301 --> Internal (page)
  -- Docs (category)
  -- Policy (category)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a customised 'landing page' using a template file?

Creating category-internal.php with custom layout would display content at the /category/internal/ url.

Here is some more info:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-category-templates-in-wordpress/

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Do you know of a good online tutorial that'll show me how to do this?

Comment: Sure, here are a couple of links. First is WordPress codex page that explains a bit more on the concept, then a tutorial.

Comment: (Added them to answer)